# Apache httpclient package show that many other packages are missing

Tags: java, apache

I downloaded apache HttpClient package. I imported entire contents. It shows errors in all subpackages. some have this type of import `import org.apache.http.HttpHost;`. Now there is not HttpHost in the package. Howver I can successfully import this

```
import org.apache.http.auth.*;
import org.apache.http.client.*;
```

Then I try to use HttpClient class like so:

```
HttpClient hc = new HttpClient();
```

It gives error that HttpClient class abstract. What is wrong here? What are all those additional imports which are just not present in the actual downloadable package !!!

Comment: how did you import it to your project?

Comment: I am using NetBeans. I clicked on properties of main project. Then in `Sources` I added package folder under the pane of Source Package Folder. There I navigated to folder containing org folder of httpclient package and that's it.

Comment: What you need to do is add external library, and instead add the source to your project you just reference a JAR file. The JAR file for HTTPClient can be downloaded here: http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi (in binaries).

Comment: ok, that was total foolishness:\ I downloaded the jar. Then in project properties->libraries I added that jar. But I cannot import `org.apache.http.client`. NetBeans says that such package just doesn't exist. I have added that jar, what's the holdup now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution would be:

1. download httpcomponents-client-4.2-bin from http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi;
2. inflate it somewhere;
3. right click on your project (your Project @ NetBeans) and select Properties
4. select item named Libraries on the tree;
5. click on Add JAR/Folder button on Tab (Compile);
6. select all JAR files contained on **httpcomponents-client-4.2/lib** (inflated file).
7. click ok.

That's it! You should be able to use `HTTPClient`.

Comment: yes got it. thanks. Now I am trying to create a sample program. `HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();` gives error that `DefaultHttpClient` does not exist. imports are `import org.apache.http.*;
import org.apache.http.client.*;`

Comment: DefaultHttpClient I think is from the version 3, the old one, I recommend the use of the version 4. Otherwise follow same process with [commons-httpclient-3.0.zip](http://archive.apache.org/dist/httpcomponents/commons-httpclient/3.0/binary/commons-httpclient-3.0.zip)